# SPFx web part which render an HTML BOX which have a configurable Title, Description and Clickable Button

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, spfx, spfx-webparts, modern-experience

I want to build an SPFx web part, which should allow me to display this Box:

[image]

Where the Box will have a configurable Title, Description text & clickable button.

So the user can add this web part inside any modern page, and define the Title, Description, button title & the button URL.

Is there any available SPFx which can allow me to have these features?

If the answer is No, is it possible to build such SPFx?

Answer (score 0):

I just checked all SPFx web part samples shared by community members on GitHub repository. But, there is no sample which exactly matches your requirements.

You can also check all the samples at: [SPFx web part samples](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples)

---

But, I am sure that this can easily be achieved using SPFx capabilities. Check below samples to see how much configurable web parts you can build using SPFx:

1. [Tiles](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-tiles)
2. [Tiles V2](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-tiles-v2)

Below documentations will help you to get started with SPFx development.

**Official documentations**:

1. [Overview of the SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview)
2. [Set up your SharePoint Framework development environment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment)
3. [Build your first SharePoint client-side web part](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part)

Comment: ok thanks for the documentation and the reply.. but since i do no thave much knowledge in SPFX , so i am asking about the steps required to implement such an SPFx..

Comment: You should have development experience to develop a custom SPFx web part. Explaining steps for development environment setup, coding & solutioning is impossible in single answer here. This should be created by your development team OR you can hire freelance developer if possible,

Comment: i have a development experience but not in SPFX.. so why not wait an see if someone will post a steps to create such SPFx...

Comment: Sure, first of all you have to [setup development environment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment) & then you try [building your first SPFx web part](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part). You will get basic idea of SPFx development.